# Loading just registration component in a modal

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I need to be able to display the registration part of the com_users component within a module.  Redirecting to the registration is not an option (design requirement.) I have found the JComponentHelper, but documentation seems to be lacking giving me enough information figure things out.

```
$component = JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_users');
```

I have created a basic module for making this work but I'm not having any luck at the moment. Help?

EDIT:

I've managed to get it to display the form somewhat, but not exactly right.  On the home page, the code displays before any header output. If I go to a sub page, the form actually displays where I want it on the page.  This may not be even the right path to solving the problem.

This is the default.php of my test module at the moment.

```
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view',null);
$layout = JRequest::getCmd('layout',null);
$task   = JRequest::getCmd('task',null);

JRequest::setVar('view', 'registration');
JRequest::setVar('layout', 'default');
JRequest::setVar('task', 'display');

$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_users', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

if (!class_exists('UsersController')) {
    require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR .DS. 'components' .DS. 'com_users'.DS. 'controller.php');
}
$controller = new UsersController();
$controller->execute('register');
//$controller->redirect();

// revert system vars to previous state
if ($view != null) {
    JRequest::setVar('view', $view);
}

if ($layout != null) {
    JRequest::setVar('layout', $layout);
}

if ($task != null) {
    JRequest::setVar('task', $task);
}
```

Comment: do you need the the registration in a modal or a module ? your title says one thing, your post another. If it's a module, it already exists...

Comment: Well, in a module.  The basic design requirement has a 'click on registration' link that opens a css popup box with the registration form.  I'm sorry I wasn't too clear. I'm still relatively new to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

After clarification, i understand that you want the registration form to open in modal, from your registration module.

So, first thing is problably to copy the regular joomla mod_login.
then, in the layout, add bootstrap modal that will contains the registration form (it can be custom).

Then, for the registration form itself, don't post to com_users, but instead use com_ajax to post back to your module helper.php. Once your module helper.php does the registration, you can display a custom layout that will display the result in the modal.

see: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface#Module_Support